# Grouping several dates on results per month in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table on a Postgres server that is consistently updated with new dates (with the oldest date being 3 years ago) but for sake of simplicity, let's just bring up 3 records:

```
id      date1         date2        date3 
1245    01/04/2018    05/04/2018   03/05/2018   
1255    01/04/2018    01/06/2018   04/06/2018 
1231    03/05/2018    07/05/2018   07/06/2018
1234    01/04/2017    01/04/2017   01/06/2018
```

I would like to create an sql view that will give me a total count of units per type of date

```
month     date1 date2 date3    
Jun       0     1     3   
May       1     1     1 
Apr       2     1     0
Apr17     1     1     0
```

Is there a simple way to do that? My sql so far looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW monthly_view 
AS
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY b.id) AS id,
       'month',
       count(*) as date1,
       count(*) as date2,
       count(*) as date3
FROM mytable b
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month desc
```

But obviously doesn't work

Comment: Do you want the count irrespective of year? For example, do you want **July 2018** and **July 2017** to both show up in the count for **July**?

Comment: @Zack nope, July 2018 and July 2017 are completely apart in time, so they will have different numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested!**

Luffydude, 
you want to do a bad thing, but that is solution ;)

```
    --all months
    with allmonths as (
        select to_char(date1, 'TMmon') as mm from tmp_a
        union
        select to_char(date2, 'TMmon') as mm from tmp_a
        union
        select to_char(date3, 'TMmon') as mm from tmp_a
    ),
    --count_in_date1
    count_in_date1 as (
        select
            t1.mm,
            count(t2.date1) as count_in_date1
        from
            allmonths t1 left join tmp_a t2 
                on to_char(t2.date1, 'TMmon') = t1.mm
        group by 
            t1.mm
    ),
    --count_in_date2
    count_in_date2 as (
        select
            t1.mm,
            count(t2.date2) as count_in_date2
        from
            allmonths t1 left join tmp_a t2 
                on to_char(t2.date2, 'TMmon') = t1.mm
        group by 
            t1.mm
    ),
    --count_in_date3
    count_in_date3 as (
        select
            t1.mm,
            count(t2.date3) as count_in_date3
        from
            allmonths t1 left join tmp_a t2 
                on to_char(t2.date3, 'TMmon') = t1.mm
        group by 
            t1.mm
    )
    --join all count together
    select t1.mm, count_in_date1, count_in_date2, count_in_date3 
    from count_in_date1 t1, count_in_date2 t2, count_in_date3 t3
        where t1.mm=t2.mm and t1.mm=t3.mm
```

Comment: It runs but it somehow is returning wrong results. Are you aggregating all months regardless of the year?

Comment: It gives exactly the same results what were descripted in your post. Sorry, you need to replace `tmp_a` to a your table name

Comment: Are you aggregating all months regardless of the year?  
>> Yes

Comment: Yea well July 2018 is a completely different month than July 2017

Comment: Do you want to see only last three months of last year or what ?  or a statisctic over all months and years ?

Comment: I need to see the full log, so around 3 years of history, plus every month as it goes along. that's the purpose of the view

Comment: Please, replace every `TMmon` to `YYYY-TMmon` and see results

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!! Just one last thing, is it possible to order the results by time? As it stands the list goes 2018-apr, 2018-aug, 2018-feb

Comment: Add `order by t1.mm` at the end of the script

Comment: it doesn't order them, still going jul, jun, oct, dec, apr

Comment: yeah, you only need to use format 'YYYY-MM' instead 'YYYY-TMmon'

Answer (score 1):

Start by generating the months.  Then I think correlated subqueries are a simple way of doing the calculation:

```
select v.mon,
       (select count(*)
        from mytable t
        where to_char(date1, 'mon') = v.mon
       ) as date1,
       (select count(*)
        from mytable t
        where to_char(date2, 'mon') = v.mon
       ) as date2,
       (select count(*)
        from mytable t
        where to_char(date3, 'mon') = v.mon
       ) as date3
from (values ('jun', 6), ('may', 5), ('apr', 4)
     ) v(mon, mm) 
order by mm desc;
```

EDIT:

Although the above should be pretty reasonable, the following might have better performance:

```
select mon, sum( (which = 1)::int ) as date1, sum( (which = 2)::int ) as date2,
       sum( (which = 3)::int ) as date3
from t cross join lateral
     (values (1, to_char(date1, 'mon'), extract(month from date1)),
             (2, to_char(date2, 'mon'), extract(month from date2)),
             (3, to_char(date3, 'mon'), extract(month from date3))
     ) v(which, mon, mm)
group by mon, mm
order by mm desc;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/DKZRT33468) is a rextester.

Comment: I'm getting a ERROR:  relation "t" does not exist after replacing your values with my table

Comment: @Luffydude . . . That is your table name.

Comment: you had a from t before you edited. anyway I now replaced it with my table and also the values with my table but the query has been running for over 10 minutes, even if your query works this is too slow for a report view that people need to look at regularly

Comment: @Luffydude . . . How large is your table?

Comment: @Luffydude . . . The code would be reading the logs either 9 or 36 times.  That should not take 10 minutes on 180k rows, unless the rows are really, really big.  In any case, I offered another solution which is more scalable.

Comment: This one works now instantly, but it's showing wrong results somehow just like the answer above

Comment: it works for me too but it only shows 12 months rather than the full log and the counts are wrong

Comment: @Luffydude  . . . Perhaps you need to ask another question with more clarity on what you want to do.  This question is answered, and answered with code that produces exactly the results specified on the data specified.

Comment: Apologies if not clear enough but my table does not only have 3 entries, it has 180k and around 3 years of history, your code only returns a third of the time period and somehow the numbers are greater than what happens in reality (if I count how many units have date3 in Aug 2018 I have around 2k, your code returns 3k)

Comment: @Luffydude . . . Your question is explicitly *not including the year*.  That is why my answers do not include the year.  If you have a question with year and month, then ask it as a separate question, with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was pretty explicit the fact that July 2018 and July 2017 are different